# Магические методы

Tags: python, ооп, python-internals

Как реализована архитектура магических методов в python?
Например:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __repr__(self):
        return "({})".format(self.x)

a = SomeClass(23)
print(repr(a))
```

Т.е. как происходит определние вызова нужного метода нужного класса? (**repr** класса SomeClass)?

Comment: Я не очень понял ваш вопрос, но у вас в коде есть ошибка, которая никак не связана с магическими методами. Вместо строчки `return "({x})".format(x)` должно быть
`return "({})".format(self.x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Немного дополню предыдущие ответы. Согласно официальной документации, вот [тут](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names), специальные методы (именно так называются магические методы в документации) это подход python к *перегрузке операторов*, позволяющий классам определять свое поведение в *отношении операторов языка*. Из этого можно заключить, что интерпретатор имеет "некую таблицу" (назовём это так) соответствия операторов к методам класса. Перегружая эти методы, вы можете управлять "поведением" операторов языка относительно вашего класса.

Также, если в некотором классе сделать любой специальный (магический) метод None, то это будет означать, что данная операция для некоторого класса не доступна, а соответствующий оператор, применённый к этому классу, вернет TypeError.

Сигнатуру функции *repr* для СPython, вы можете посмотреть только в исходниках на С.
В модуле builtins.py она выглядит следующим образом

```
def repr(obj): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
    """
    Return the canonical string representation of the object.

    For many object types, including most builtins, eval(repr(obj)) == obj.
    """
    pass
```

Но думаю тут и так понятно.

Создавая свой класс без наследников, вы неявно наследуете класс *object*
со всеми его специальными методами включая и ***repr***. В модуле builtins.py это выглядит так:

```
class object:
    """ The most base type """
    .... # ещё порядка 20 магических методов
    def __repr__(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """ Return repr(self). """
    pass
```

Таким образом можно сделать, ещё один вывод, что даже "пустой" пользовательский класс, готов для применения, в том или ином виде, операторами (функциями) языка.

И ещё немного о соответствии [тут](http://www.diveintopython3.net/special-method-names.html)

Comment: Были предположения, что всё идет от object. Спасибо, теперь разъяснили

Comment: В Питоне 2, `repr(obj)` работает даже для объектов, которые не наследуются от
`object`. И обратное, объекты типа `object` не обязаны определять все
специальные методы (`getattr(object(), '__add__')`).

Answer (score 4):

[Магический метод](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-special-method) — это просто метод, который вызывается неявно, часто чтобы выполнить операцию для типа. К примеру, можно определить [`__bool__` метод](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__), чтобы указать является ли объект `True/False` в булевом контексте (если поведение по умолчанию, основанное на `__len__` или `True`, не подходит). Очень многие аспекты поведения объектов в Питоне могут быть изменены таким образом. К примеру, [`plumbum` модуль](https://plumbum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#piping), за счёт перегрузки операторов, встраивает [`sh`-подобный язык прямо в Питон](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16709666/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from plumbum.cmd import awk, sort

(awk["-f", "script.awk"] << "input data" | sort > "outfile.txt")()
```

Здесь определены `__getitem__`(`[]`), `__lshift__`(`<<`), `__or__`(`|`), `__gt__`(`>`), `__call__`(`()`) методы.

> Как реализована архитектура магических методов в python?
> Как происходит определение вызова нужного метода нужного класса?

`repr(SomeClass())` приводит к вызову `SomeClass.__repr__` (если определён), потому что [документация `repr()` функции так говорит](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr).

В целом, ничего особенно не происходит, к примеру, вы можете свой протокол определить:

```
def quack(obj):
    return getattr(obj, 'quack', None)()
```

Любой объект, для которого определён метод `quack()`, *независимо от его базовых классов*, можно передать в функцию quack():

```
class Duck:
    def quack(self):
        return "Quack! Quack! Quack!"

print(quack(Duck()))
```

Для остальных классов `TypeError` выбрасывается:

```
try:
    quack(1)
except TypeError:
    print("целое число не квакает")
```

Отличие `quack()` от [настоящих магических методов](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names), что не используется *двойное подчёркивание в имени метода, по соглашению*, зарезервированное для протоколов, определяемых самим языком и нет требования [*определить метод в самом классе* (определения из Мета-класса или присваивание метода объекту напрямую могут не работать для магических методов)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup):

```
>>> class C:
...     pass    
>>> c = C()    
>>> c.__len__ = lambda: 0    
>>> len(c)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'C' has no len()
```

Для сравнения, `quack()` можно прямо самому объекту присвоить:

```
>>> c.quack = lambda: "ga ga"
>>> quack(c)
'ga ga'
```

Но чтобы `len()` работала, необходимо определение в сам класс помещать:

```
>>> class C:
...     def __len__(self):
...         return 0

>>> len(C())
0
```

Это сделано для оптимизации скорости вызова подобных методов и чтобы избежать ["metaclass confusion", описанную выше по ссылке](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup). В CPython, [почти все специальные методы](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-special-method) (термин для магических методов из спецификации языка) [хранятся в специальных слотах в типе](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e82cf8675bacd7a03de508ed11865fc2701dcef5/Objects/typeobject.c#L6626-L6872).

Answer (score 0):

посмотрите на этот вопрос так

```
def __repr__(self):
     return "({x})".format(x=self.x)

class SomeClass:pass

a = SomeClass()
a.x = 23

print(__repr__(a))
```