# Python len() и .__len__() в чем разница?

Tags: python, python-internals

В чем разница между len() и `.__len__()`? И могут ли они возвращать разные значения?

Comment: [difference between len() and .__len__()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2481421/2881286)

Comment: Обычно `len()` вызывает `.__len__()`, кроме тех случаев, когда у объекта есть более быстрая C-шная реализация.

Comment: `__len__` магический метод, его можно перегрузить. Но разница не большая. Так как `len()` --> `__len__`

Comment: связанный вопрос [Why is `str(super(B, b))` not equivalent to `super(B, b).__str__()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46913287/4279)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__len__` это магический метод, который реализует `len` операцию.
Как и любой другой специальный метод, он вызывается специальным образом (должен быть определён в самом классе), то есть `len(o)` не всегда эквивалентно `o.__len__()`. Подробнее в [ответе о магических методах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647069/23044).

Дополнительно, значения `len()` ограничены `sys.maxsize`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> class Big:
...     def __len__(self):
...         return sys.maxsize + 1
...     
>>> len(Big())
Traceback (most recent call last)
...
OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer
>>> Big().__len__()
9223372036854775808
```

На практике, иногда полезно иметь последовательность с большой длиной:

- [Get the highest possible gmtime for any architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32045725/4279)
- [Weighted random sample in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13047806/4279)

Answer (score 3):

Для встроенных классов (list, dict, tuple, ...) функция `len(o)` не вызывает `o.__len__()`, а напрямую вызывает функцию `o->tp_as_sequence->sq_length(o)` (реализована на С) (благодарю [@jfs за подсказку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/695218/python-len-%d0%b8-len-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0/695241?noredirect=1#comment1031126_695241)). Для остальных классов функция `len(o)` вызывает `o.__len__()`.

Интересное наблюдение:

```
In [137]: l = list(range(10**6))

In [138]: %timeit len(l)
The slowest run took 8.91 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 314 ns per loop

In [139]: %timeit l.__len__()
The slowest run took 8.42 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 388 ns per loop
```

Похоже для объектов встроенных классов `obj.__len__()` немного медленнее по сравнению с `len(obj)`.

Если же реализовать `__len__` в собственном классе, то будет наоборот, т.к. `len(obj)` это обертка (wrapper) над `obj.__len__()` (для объектов "не встроенных" классов)

Пример:

```
In [152]: class my_len:
     ...:     def __len__(self):
     ...:         return 1
     ...:

In [153]: a = my_len()

In [154]: %timeit len(a)
The slowest run took 8.22 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 624 ns per loop

In [155]: %timeit a.__len__()
The slowest run took 8.95 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 365 ns per loop
```

---

**UPDATE:** [вот ответ поясняющий почему `len(o)` для встроенных типов работает быстрее чем `o.__len__()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20302670/5741205):

> The builtin `len()` function does not look up the `.__len__`
>   attribute. It looks up the [`tp_as_sequence`
>   pointer](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#tp_as_sequence),
>   which in turn has a [`sq_length`
>   attribute](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#PySequenceMethods.sq_length).
>
> The `.__len__` attribute on built-in objects is indirectly [mapped to
>   the same
>   slot](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/30b3798782f1/Objects/typeobject.c#l6001),
>   and it is that indirection (plus the attribute lookup) that takes more
>   time.
>
> For Python-defined classes, the `type` object looks up the `.__len__`
>   method when the `sq_length` is requested.

Comment: где длина хранится не важно. Вы можете вызывать (но не следует) `__len__` метод и у обычного списка: `[].__len__()`. И обратное: `len(o)` использует специальный способ вызова `__len__` и в определённых пользователем классах, а не только для встроенных типов. См. [Магические методы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/646280/23044).

Comment: @jfs, вы уверены, что для встроенных типов `len(o)` вызывает `o.__len__()`?  Как можно объяснить тот факт, что для встроенных типов `len(o)` быстрее чем `o.__len__()`?

Comment: Пройдите по ссылкам, прочтите как вызываются специальные методы (что происходит когда вы `len(o)` вызываете. Исходный код говорит: `o->ob_type->tp_as_sequence->sq_length(o)` для последовательностей). Сравните как обычный вызов `o.__len__()` происходит (`o.__dict__`, `type(o).__dict__`, [descriptor протокол](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)). Подумайте, почему `len(o)` не работает, если `__len__` вне класса определить (а `o.__len__()` продолжает работать).

Comment: @jfs, спасибо! Теперь понял почему `len(o)` отрабатывает быстрее чем `o.__len__()` для встроенных типов

Comment: акцент на "встроенности" класса вводит в заблуждение. Всё что я сказал выше относится как к классам, определённым в С так и к классам, определённым в Питоне (`__len__` является специальным методом, вне зависимости где класс определён в С или в Питоне). sq_length и так и так вызывается — разница только в том на что она указывает. К примеру, для списка это list_length С функция, которая просто `->ob_size` возвращает. Если пройти по ссылке, которую я привёл, то  в моём ответе о магических методах последняя ссылка выделяет таблицу, которая показывает что `__len__` отображается на slot_sq_length.

Comment: Именно slot_sq_length ищет `__len__` на типе (`->ob_type->tp_mro[i]->tp_dict["__len__"]`). Обратите внимание, что это отличается от поиска, вызванного выражением `o.__len__` (как я уже выше упомянул).

Comment: Более того, если мы вообще о sq_length и CPython забудем, то `__len__` всё равно специальным методом останется (со [специальным поиском](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup) -- опять таки ссылка из моего ответа о магических методах. Я не просто так сказал, "пройдите по ссылкам")

Answer (score 0):

да они возвращают разные значения. Например len() возвращает количество елементов в списке

```
>>> s = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'q']
>>> len(s)
5
```

А метод **len** может использоваться только в классе и для списков возвращает его содержимое

```
    >>> class qwerty:
    def __len__(self):
        q = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'q']
        return q


>>> qwerty().__len__()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'q']
>>>
```