# В чем принципиальное различие между инструкцией оператором и операцией?

Tags: python, алгоритм, структуры

Заметил что в рускоязычной литературе присуствует небольшой бардак в терминологии. Многие авторы (или переводчики) вводят путаницу в таких терминах как - инструкция, оператор, операция - А можно ли провести четкую грань между ними?.. Например присваивание это оператор или операция? И в чем тогда принципиальное отличие его внутренней реализации, допустим, от сложения, позволяющее однозначно отнести к тому или другому термину?

Comment: По идее инструкции есть только в ассемблере

Comment: @evgeny-shmidt однако же пишут... у лутца например так  написано - "...программы деляться на модули, модули содержат инструкции, которые состоят из выражаений, обрабатывающих объекты с помощью операторов..." что-то же он имел ввиду ))

Comment: таких примеров масса на самом деле

Comment: @Amunrah Ну в конкретно приведенном вами примере автор под _инструкцией_ явно понимает одно крупное действие, которое должен выполнить язык. примерно в таком виде "Инструкция: 1. сложи A и B; 2. от результата отними C; 3. положи результат в D" и она состоит из 3 операторов, сложения, вычитания и присваивания. Но автор пошел еще дальше, укрупняя это понятие, написав, что оно состоит из выражений, я бы лично выражением назвал только что описанный пример. В общем в данном случае это не общепринятый термин, а некое обобщение, удобное автору.

Comment: И с точки зрения терминологии, оператор, это атомарное действие, обычно использующее один или два параметра (единственное исключение: тернарный оператор, принимающий 3 параметра)

Comment: @Mike Хорошо, вижу вы тоже путаетесь, я переформулировал вопрос...

Comment: Я не путаюсь, я лишь пытаюсь показать, что в программировании есть только один термин, "_оператор_", который понимается как единое, атомарное (с точки зрения конкретного языка) действие. (так названный в стандартах языка, мнение конкретного автора книги при этом не учитывается). Все остальное - это не общепринятые термины, а лишь слова, которые все применяют по своему разумению, а следовательно обозначающие разные понятия в разных источниках

Comment: @Mike Не поймите не правильно, я лишь пытаюсь разобраться. Например сложение в той же википедии это операция, а присваивание это уже оператор. При этом там же (в вики) предлагают не путать эти два понятия... но эти действия оба едины и атомарны, с точки зрения языка (если я вас правильно понял)...

Comment: А где утверждается что есть только оператор? поделитесь ссылкой, с удовольствием ознакомлюсь...

Comment: В той статье в вики, на которую вы ссылаетесь, как раз объясняется откуда берется путаница. Я под "оператор" понимаю "operator" и в тонкости русского языка не вдаюсь. Того же придерживаются и многие переводчики, ибо практически все первоисточники на английском языке. например: https://wombat.org.ua/AByteOfPython/operators_and_expressions.html  (и если честно, описанное в вики для меня новость, не видел переводов, где бы operator называли "операция", скорее наоборот, видел переводы, где под "операция" понималась инструкция (ассемблерная))

Comment: @mike Да, наверно из-за нее и возникла путаница. В вики оператор (он же инструкция) - statement, а операция - operator... Мне просто не совсем понятно почему присваивание это statement, а сложение это operator... в чем принципиальная разница в их внутренней реализации?... или в англ источниках они оба operator и это ошибка переводчика?.. (за статью спасибо)

Comment: Сложение, вычитание и т.п. в русскоязычных источниках по математике принято называть "операция", а присвоения в математике нет. отсюда возможно и различия, вносимые переводчиком. Или не переводчиком, судя по гуглу присвоение (assignment) с одинаковым успехом называют как operator так и statement. Лично я привык придерживаться точки зрения компилятора языка, для которого присвоение ни чем фундаментальным не отличается от сложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "модули содержат инструкции, которые состоят из выражений, обрабатывающих объекты с помощью операторов"<sup>[из комментария автора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/807336/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc#comment1278206_807336)</sup>

Здесь "инструкции" это перевод слова statements ([stmt в грамматике языка](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html?highlight=stmt)).

Есть простые инструкции типа: `import m`, `return v`, `n=1`, ... Есть составные: `for`, `while`, `with`, ...

Выражение ([expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html)) характерно тем, что значение имеет: `n`, `n+1`, `{1:'a'}`, `await coro`, ...

Операторы (operators, how) представляют собой знак/действие, указывающий на/реализующее соответствующую операцию (operation, what) — это как функции, но со специальным встроенным в язык синтаксисом. К примеру, операторы сравнения [из грамматики](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html?highlight=comp_op):

```
comp_op: '<'|'>'|'=='|'>='|'<='|'<>'|'!='|'in'|'not' 'in'|'is'|'is' 'not'
```

Пример: `1 is 1`. Ещё пример: сложение это операция, для которой используется оператор `+` в Питоне, соответствующий `__add__` [специальному методу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647069/23044). Операция это "что" (определяет что на входе, что на выходе), а оператор это символ, функция ("как" из ввода, вывод получается).

Список cтандартных операторов в Питоне, можно в [operator модуле посмотреть](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions).

> **Q:** присваивание это оператор или операция?

В Питоне `a=b` это [statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=assignment#assignment-statements), одна из [name binding operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html). В Википедии вы вероятно увидели слово оператор в значении statement (вряд ли операция привязки имён, характерная для Питона, имелась в виду). В русской Википедии можно встретить ["русский термин «оператор» обозначает то же, что и «инструкция»"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Это не наш случай (см. выше).

Comment: Спасибо. Интересный ответ. А можно чуть подробнее на счет выражений? К сожалению не совсем уловил смысл...

Comment: @Amunrah: что бы вы хотели о них узнать?

Comment: Как можно перефразировать определение Лутца (его перевод, если уж быть точным) в тезисах из вашего ответа? )

Comment: @Amunrah: Приведённая цитата, не является слишком строгой. Если вас чисто формальная сторона интересует, то смотрите grammar и другие ссылки на спецификацию языка. Если неформально, то попробуйте вопрос задать, который можно выразить в терминах рабочей программы, которая какие-то результаты получает, которых вы не ожидали. Не понимаю какой результат ожидается, к чему перефразировать фразу с самыми базовыми определениями без использования этих самых базовых терминов.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда еще вопрос для уточнения, будет ли правильным назвать инструкцию и ее результат операцией?

Comment: @Amunrah: это разные слова, описывают разные понятия. При общении иногда разные слова, описывающие разные понятия, можно взаимозаменяемо употребить в некоторых случаях. К примеру, имя и объект, на который оно ссылается, в разговоре иногда взаимозаменяемо может употребляться -- если не обсуждаются проблемы, специфичные к именованию объектов. При этом имя и объект это разные слова, обозначающие разные понятия. Инструкция может реализовать какую-нибудь операцию (но это разные вещи).

Comment: Всего лишь пытаюсь уточнить ) Если операция это функция вызываемая особым оператором с аргументами в виде операндов, то чем тогда является инструкция? Она ведь вроде тоже возвращает значение и имеет особую форму записи, которую интерпретатор также во что-то разворачивает... буду благодарен, если подскажете что почитать для ликвидации безграмотности в этом вопросе.

Comment: @Amunrah operator.add это функция, которая может операцию сложения реализовать. Операция это не Питон-функция, а идея. В других контекстах слова операция, функция могут другие значения принимать.¶ Даже спецификация Питона написана простым языком, ориентированным на понимание, а не на строгость в первую очередь¶ Если вы не можете создать/ не встречаете примеры кода, которые неожиданно для вашего понимания Питона работают (предсказали одно, фактически другое получили), значит модель у вас неправдоподобно хорошая (все модели ложны, некоторые полезны).

Comment: Похоже в целом все верно, кроме того, что операция в вашем изложении по сути это выражение... ) елси пользоваться английскими терминами, то есть только - statement, expression и operator - инструкция, выражение и операция соответсвенно.

Comment: @Amunrah неверно. Слово operator в ответе переводится как оператор. К чему вы думаете предложение в ответе: "это не наш случай".  Слово операция это operation (явно указано в ответе). В любом случае operator, operation, expression это разные слова (со стандартными значениями для темы программирования из документации Питона). Если вы не можете пример кода предоставить, который ведёт не так как вы ожидаете, то не вижу пользы от подобной дискуссии (см. мои предыдущие комментарии).

Comment: Просто пытался озвучить то что для меня выглядит противоречиво. Пример кода для иллюстрации придумать сложно, так как, по большому счету, его ожидаемое поведение врядли измениться назови действие операцией или выражением... Не ставлю целью именно спор, повторюсь - в целом ваш ответ меня вполне устраивает. Спасибо.

Comment: @Amunrah: что конкретно выглядит "противоречиво" -- приведите прямую цитату из ответа и как вы её понимаете? У вас похоже представление, что если в одном случае разные слова можно к одному и тому же явлению применить, то слова становятся "по сути" одним и тем же -- это неправильно. Может вам пример из другой области поможет: если мы сказали: "вот человек, его зовут Ваня" -- это не значит, что  "человек" и "Ваня"  это одно и то же (не все люди Вани, не все Вани являются людьми (есть ураган Ivan) и слова вообще из разных категорий).