# Изменение id объекта внутри DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Вопрос относительно изменения объекта внутри DataFrame.
Выполняю в Jupiter следующий код:

```
In [1]:
data1 = data['Churn']
data2 = data1.astype('int64')
```

data - DataFrame c полем Chunk.

Далее в отдельной ячейке вывожу id объектов внутри data1 и data2 последовательно 2 раза:

```
In [2]:
for _ in range(2):
    print('data1 - ', id(data1))
    print('data2 - ', id(data2))
    print('data1[0] - ', id(data1[0]))
    print('data2[0] - ', id(data2[0]))
    print('---')
```

В итоге:

> ```
> data1 -  97384048
> data2 -  98333360
> data1[0] -  70340008
> data2[0] -  95222752
> ---
> data1 -  97384048
> data2 -  98333360
> data1[0] -  70340008
> data2[0] -  95222784
> ---
> ```

Последний объект `data2[0]` изменился. Просто при последовательном считывании.
Как такое может происходить?

Comment: что значит "Просто при последовательном считывании"?

Comment: Вы можете пояснить - зачем вы сравниваете `id()` ячеек?

Comment: Исключительно для понимания как Python работает с переменными и памятью. Дабы в дальнейшем не получить ошибку, связанную с непониманием этих процессов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` это имя. В цикле вы его не привязываете к другому объекту, поэтому встроенная функция `id()` возвращает одно и то же значение (один объект — одно значение id).

Из того что вы видите `id(data[0])` меняется, следует, что `data[0]` разные объекты возвращает. Можно убедиться:

```
>>> a = data[0]
>>> b = data[0]
>>> a is not b
True
```

Индексация реализуется в Питоне с помощью `__getitem__()` [специального метода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647069/23044), который в данном случае создаёт новый Питон объект при каждом обращении. Внутри вероятно массив int64 компактно хранится — Си данные плюс метадата (размеры)), а индексируя вы из Сишного int64, создаёте Питон int объект.

Связанный вопрос (обратная проблема — разные имена, но один int объект): [Что такое объект в Python. Почему id(a) == id(b) == id(1)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662398/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Это ничего чудесного. Для документации стандартной библиотеки Питона  ([The Python Standard Library - 2. Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#id)):

> ```
>  id(object)
>
>     Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed 
>     to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. 
>     Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
> ```

Переведено на русский язык:

> ```
>  id(объект)
>
>     Возвращает “идентичность” объекта. Это целое число, причем гарантировано,
>     что оно будет единственным и неизменяемым для этого объекта во время периода 
>     его существования. 
>     Два объекты с не перекрывающими периодами существования могут 
>     иметь тот-же самое значение id().
> ```

`data2` объект *с периодом существования*, и так *гарантирована неизменность его значения* `id` во время этого периода.

Но `data2[0]` только *переходный объект*, который может быть *снова и снова создан*, значит *даже с другим `id`.*